# Understanding a Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, correlated-subquery

I want to create a query that returns the most recent date for a date field and the highest value of a integer field for each "assessment" record. What I think is required is a correlated subquery and using the MAX function.

example data would be as follows

the date field could have duplicate dates for each assessment but each duplicate date group would have a different the integer in the integer field. 
eg

1256    2/6/14    0
1256    2/6/14    1
1256    1/6/14    0
4534    3/6/14    0
4534    3/6/14    1
4534    3/6/14    2

```
select assessment, Max(correctnum) maxofcorrectnum, dateeffect
from lraassm outerassm
where dateeffect =
    (select MAX(dateeffect) maxofdateeffect
    from pthdbo.lraassm innerassm
    innerassm.assessment = outerassm.assessment
    group by innerassm.assessment)
group by assessment, dateeffect
```

so my theory is that the inner query executes and gives the outer query the criteria for the dateeffect field in the outer query and then the outer query would return the maximum of the correctnum field for this dateeffect and also return its corresponding assessment and the dateeffect.

Could someone please confirm this is correct. How does the subquery handle the rows? what other ways are there to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: for your data (above) please show your expected outcome

Comment: so if the above sample data all had the same assessment number the result would be 3/6/14  2
if there were multiple assessment numbers for example row 1, 2 and 3 had the same assessment number and rows 4,5 and 6 had a different assessment number the result would be 2 rows 2/6/14   1 and 3/6/14 2. hope that makes sense. so it would be grouped by assessment number

Answer (score 0):

Your query is doing the right thing, but granted, the correlated subquery is a little difficult to understand. What the subquery does is, it filters the records based on `assessment` from the outer query and then returns the maximum dateeffect for that assessment. In fact, you don't need the `group by` clause on the correlated query.

These types of queries are where common when working with data in ERP systems, when you're only interested in "latest" records, etc. This is also known as a "top segment" type of query (which the query optimizer is sometimes able to figure out by itself). I've found, that on SQL Server 2005 or newer, it is a lot easier to use the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function. The following query should return the same as yours, namely one record from `lraassm` for each `assessment`, that has the highest value of dateeffect and correctnum.

```
select * from (
    select 
        assessment, dateeffect, correctnum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY assessment, 
             ORDER BY dateeffect DESC, correctnum DESC
        ) AS segment
    from lraassm) AS innerQuery
where segment = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I worked out using my tables. But it will get you on the right track and you should be able to substitute your fields/tables in.

```
 Select * from Decode
 where updated_time = (Select MAX(updated_time)from DECODE)
```

That Query gives you every record that has the most recent updated_time. The next query will return the greatest entry_id value as well as the most recent updated_time from those Records

```
Select MAX(entry_id), updated_time from Decode
where updated_time = (Select MAX(updated_time)from DECODE)
group by updated_time
```

The result is 2 columns 1 record, 1st column is the Maximum value of entry id, the second is the most recent updated_time. Is that what you wanted to return?

Comment: so the result would be for each assessment group get the latest date and if there are multiple records with that date then get the max entry_id. Also an assessment can have many dates and can have duplicate dates but each duplicated date gets given a sequential integer to show its order.